# Bash split file on double newline

Tags: bash

I have some files with content that change from file to file.
Each file have 2 sections of lines separated by a blank line.
I never know how many lines or characters there are in either section.

The file can look something like this.

```
This is a file
with some text

and some more text
```

This code only gives the first line from each section.

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n\n"; FS="\n";} {print $1 }' file
```

I need each section split up to work with.

Comment: Do you need those in separate files? Do you need those in separate shell variables? Can you do the operations on them you need in `awk` directly and use the combined output?

Comment: If you want `awk` answers, tag this `awk`, not `bash`. Tagging it `bash` implies that you want an answer written in, well, `bash`... and `awk` is not bash. (Yes, this kind of thing *can* be done in native bash with no external tools -- that is to say, no awk, no sed, no perl, etc... though for large/long inputs awk tends to be faster, and certainly much more terse). If you just want answers using UNIX tools and don't care what those are, tag it unix.

Answer (score 5):

Prints first part: 
`sed '/^$/q' test.txt`

Prints second part:
`sed '1,/^$/d' test.txt`

Comment: Very cool, but could you add an explanation or point to a reference, please?

Answer (score 4):

Since this is tagged `bash`, might as well have a native-bash solution.

```
sections=( )
current_section=
while REPLY=; IFS= read -r || [[ $REPLY ]]; do
  if [[ $REPLY ]]; then
    # preserve newlines within the sections
    if [[ $current_section ]]; then
      current_section+=$'\n'"$REPLY"
    else
      current_section+=$REPLY
    fi
  else
    sections+=( "$current_section" )
    current_section=
  fi
done <file
```

This will put your file's individual sections into a bash array called `sections`.

You can print the contents of that array like so:

```
printf -- '---\n%s\n---\n' "${sections[@]}"
```

...or iterate over it to do as you please:

```
for section in "${sections[@]}"; do
  : do something with "$section" here
done
```

Comment: Do you need the assignment of `IFS` when using `REPLY`?

Comment: No, actually. Habits, &c.

Comment: I spent way to long to understand the solution... so this might help some future readers: 1. `REPLY` automatically captures the current line when using `read`; 2. `[[ $REPLY ]]` tests if `$REPLY` is empty

Answer (score 3):

Set `RS` to a null/blank value to get awk to operate on sequences of blank lines.

From the [POSIX specification for awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06):

> **RS**
>
> The first character of the string value of RS shall be the input record separator; a  by default. If RS contains more than one character, the results are unspecified. *If RS is null, then records are separated by sequences consisting of a  plus one or more blank lines, leading or trailing blank lines shall not result in empty records at the beginning or end of the input, and a  shall always be a field separator, no matter what the value of FS is.*

Answer (score 1):

```
IFS=";"
sections=($(awk -v RS= '{print $0 ";"}' filename))
```

`IFS=;` sets the internal field separator from space (default) to a semicolon

`$(awk -v RS= '{print $0 ";"}' filename)` prints out sections separated by double new lines and outputs a `;` after each section. Another way to achieve the same result is `awk -v ORS=';' -v RS= '{print}'`

`sections=(awk_output_here)` splits the awk output based on the `IFS` and assigns each section as an array element. Hence, `$sections` contains each section split on `;`. An individual section may be accessed with `${sections[0]}` where `0` is an index.

The above *awk trick* works [because it is a use case or convention in awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html).

> Another technique is to have blank lines separate records. By a special dispensation, an empty string as the value of RS indicates that records are separated by one or more blank lines. When RS is set to the empty string, each record always ends at the first blank line encountered.

Comment: pretty convoluted, but this works well.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that there are precisely two parts, this very simple Perl trick will print the the standard output until it encounters an empty line, and then the remainder to error;

```
 perl -ne 'if (1../^$/) { print STDOUT } else { print STDERR }'
```

e.g.
   cat tmp0 | perl -ne 'if (1../^$/) { print STDOUT } else { print STDERR }' > tmp1 2> tmp2

tmp1:

```
This is a file
with some text
```

tmp2:

```
and some more text
```