# Why is search & replace parameter expansion much slower in bash than in zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh

I'm solving Advent of Code in bash/zsh and I'm reading today's input (±2000).

The input is separated by double-newlines (real input is ±2000 lines):

```
vjbzaqs
bovlts

d
r
r
p
d

erxwkjlv
jpoefrlx
kjrwxeld
```

Since IFS is single character I want to replace 2 newlines with a tab (so I can set IFS to tab and iterate the input):

```sh
input="$(cat advent-6.csv)"
input_new=${input//$'\n\n'/$'\t'}
echo $input_new
```

In zshell this is instant:

```sh
➜  bash-game time zsh ./advent-6.sh
./advent-6.sh  0.01s user 0.01s system 80% cpu 0.016 total
```

However, in bash this takes ~42 seconds:

```
➜  bash-game time bash ./advent-6.sh
bash ./advent-6.sh  42.52s user 0.04s system 99% cpu 42.590 total
```

#### Why is zsh performing so much better at search & replace parameter expansion than bash?

What's happening here?

(Note: I realise there are a million other ways to do this with sed/awk, I don't need help with replacing two newlines with tabs - if you are interested in doing this [here is an answer mentioning several ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744480/bash-split-file-on-double-newline) - I care about why they're different)

Comment: So why not? Bash implementation may just be worse, that's all. Please post your bash version and zsh version.

Comment: `bash` is slower for me, but only by a factor of threeish. And assuming your advent-6.csv is the raw data as delivered (Which isn't CSV), you'll notice the two shells will display it very differently...

Comment: Hint: `echo "$input_new"` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65155548/why-does-sh-interpret-these-commands-differently-to-zsh

Comment: @KamilCuk `zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)`, `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)` (what my mac came with), @Shawn thanks I'll take a look (it's not actually csv I just assumed, this is the raw data)

Comment: `Hint: echo "$input_new"` Yes, so note that you are measuring reading from file (maybe also `fork` with `exec(cat)`) then substituting then word splitting and filename expansion in case of bash and outputting. Would be nice to hardcode the read from file and remove `echo` and measure only substitution, then measure `echo` separately, etc. Could be that word splitting is enough to increase the time that much. Are there any `?` `*` `[` in the data?

Comment: Downvoted because this is a simple misunderstanding, caused by lack of research.

Comment: @oguzismail what lack of research? I checked both the bash hackers wiki, the bash reference manual and the zshell manual before asking. I'm not sure how much research you expect people to perform before posting? I am admittedly quite bad at zsh (which is why I'm learning)

Comment: More than that. *Note in particular the fact that words of unquoted parameters
       are not automatically split on whitespace unless the option
       SH_WORD_SPLIT is set.* is the first sentence of the second paragraph under PARAMETER EXPANSION in zsh manual.

Comment: Oh, also prefer `$(< filename)` over `$(cat filename)`.

Comment: @oguzismail I... read that section and did not see that, apologies. Even when I weak quote both lines zsh is still much much faster on my machine though

Comment: @KamilCuk There are no special characters in the file; it's just lower case letters and newlines.

Comment: OS X is bundled with an ancient version of bash. You might want to benchmark with a more modern version, in case there have been performance improvements in the last decade.